# Sorting multidimensional array of objects in php

Tags: php

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$myArray(

'totals' => array(
     Entity\Total,
     Entity\Total
     ...
)

'subtotals' => array(
     Entity\Total,
     Entity\Total
     ...
)
)
```

I'm wondering how to sort totals and subtotals arrays of objects based on field from object of class Total.

I tried something with usort and stuff with no luck. This returns duplicated arrays of unsorted objects.

```
  uasort($myArray, function($a, $b){

                    foreach($a as $adata) {
                       foreach($b as $bdata){
                        if ($adata->getmaxTotal() > $bdata->getmaxTotal())
                            return 1;
                        else
                            return 0;
                      }
                    }

            });
```

Comment: What did you try with usort? Usort is the way to go normally.

Answer (score 0):

[array_multisort](http://php.net/array_multisort) could sort several arrays at the same time. But has no analog with callback. So you need to create new array, that could be ordered with this function.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    {
    $a[$i] = new stdClass();
    $a[$i]->id = $i;
    $a[$i]->property = $i % 4;
    }

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    {
    $b[$i] = new stdClass();
    $b[$i]->id = $i;
    $b[$i]->property = $i % 3;
    }

// creating temporary array
$c = array_map(function ($item)
    { return $item->property; }, $a);
array_multisort($c, $a, $b);
var_dump($a, $b);
```